# Error in [R] VennDiagram: "Impossible...produces negative area"

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am having trouble creating a plot using VennDiagram. Below is my code and error:

```
venn.plot <- draw.quad.venn(area1 = 412, area2 = 471, area3 = 137, area4 = 1507, n12 = 11, n13 = 1, n14 = 132, n23 = 0, n24 = 183, n34 = 24, n123 = 1, n124 = 143, n134 = 18, n234 = 14, n1234 = 64, category = c("Set1", "Set2", "Set3", "Set4"), fill = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue"), lty = "dashed", cex = 2, cat.cex = 2, cat.col = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue"));

Error in draw.quad.venn(area1 = 412, area2 = 471, area3 = 137, area4 = 1507,  : 
Impossible: a5  <- n134 - a6 produces negative area
```

I checked my math, but might have missed something? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is IMHO the lack of documentation.  Try running the example code for `draw.triple.venn` .  You'll see that the values in the pairwise overlap regions consist of the argument values **minus** the 3-way argument value.  That is,

```
venn.plot <- draw.triple.venn(
    area1 = 65,
    area2 = 75,
    area3 = 85,
    n12 = 35,
    n23 = 15,
    n13 = 25,
    n123 = 5)
```

Produces a plot with '30' '20', '10' in the 2-way regions.  You'll have to do the same sort of subtraction to your input values, I suspect.

Comment: I don't understand your point. The R package did the subtraction for you altering my input as you suggested would double-subtract the 3-way overlap.

Comment: @user, yes, and your `n234 = 14, n1234 = 64` requires subtracting 64 from 14, hence the failure.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. This is going to be a pain to tease apart. Thanks for the help, Carl!

Comment: If I well understand the fact is that if you have 10 data points in area 1, 10 in area 2 and 20 in common between 1 and 2 you have to provide the value of 30 to area1 (i.e. area1 includes ALL the points that are in area1, the ones that are private and the ones that are shared). With that changes everything will run smoothly.